# Angular 4 image not found in templateURL but works in template string

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I'm using the Angular 4 universal starter https://github.com/ng-seed/universal

I'm having an issue with the templateURL finding images even though they render fine just using:

```
template: '<img src="assets/img/twitter.png" />
```

When I put the same code in the templateURL: './home.component.html' I get:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/img/twitter.png'
```

Not sure how to troubleshoot this one.  The template renders all other HTML fine, but can't locate any images.  Any idea how to solve would be great.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular points to src/assets folder

```
'<img src="/assets/img/twitter.png" />
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean.  It works fine as a template string, like you have it, but not in a template file using templateUrls.  My other Angular projects had not problem rendering images in the template.

Comment: did u put this code in html file <img src="/assets/img/twitter.png" /> .  can you post your html file

Comment: Well, I thought I tried that and it didn't work, but now seems to be working.  Thank you.